# how to pass checkbox value to controller on form submit then return data to view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In My view i placed a check box in-front of some user records .when I check a check box and click on submit button then the selected checkbox values (**user Id**) will be sent to controller. currently i successfully get emails in my model but can't get the DB result back in view.

**Customers View :**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
 <table class="table table-responsive">
 @foreach (var s in Model)
 {
  <td id="list"><input type="checkbox" name="ids" id="ids" value="@s.Id" /></td>  
 }
  <tr>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendmail" type="submit">Send Email To Customers</button></td>
  </tr>
 </table>      
}
@if (TempData["Emails"] != null)
{
<span class="alert-info">@TempData["Emails"]</span>
}
```

**Controller :**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Customers(int[] ids)
    {
        Customers cu= new Customers();
        cu.IDS = ids;
        cu.GetEmails(ids);
        TempData["ids"] = string.Join(",", ids.ToArray());
        TempData["Emails"] = cu.GetEmails(ids).Email.ToArray(); // I want these emails in my view
        return RedirectToAction("Customers");
    }
```

**Model :**

```
public Customers GetEmails(int[] ids)
    {
        Customers ee = new Customers();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mvc"].ConnectionString);
        string qry = "select Email from users where Id IN(" + string.Join(",", ids.ToArray()) + ")"; 
        SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdd = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdd.Read())
        {
          ee.Email = rdd["Email"].ToString();  // I am able to get all emails
        }
        rdd.Close();
        cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return ee;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of building up string like that (which is a pattern that is vulnerable to sql injection) I would suggest using table valued parameters instead. It is much easier and safer to work with.

Comment: i will change my code, right now it's just local testing, thank you.

Comment: so basically you need email value to your get (view)  method, isn't it?

Comment: @ZiaulKabirFahad email values based selected id's

Comment: is now `public Customers GetEmails(int[] ids)` returning emails based on ids ?

Comment: yes it's returning those email id's

Comment: well I think your code is just fine enough for pass email array or list though temp data, are they always get null in view?

Comment: i always get null value , i also tried ajax method but still no chance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181246/discussion-between-ziaul-kabir-fahad-and-mohammad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well lets start with some dummy data and test case scenario

```
 public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(MyModel model)
    {
        TempData["test"] = GetData();
        return View();
    }

    public List<string> GetData() //method for get data
    {
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[] { "element1", "element2", "element3" });
        return mylist;
    }
```

and razor view

```
var data = TempData["test"] as List<string>;
if (data != null)
{
    foreach (var a in data)
    {
        W‌riteLiteral(@"<li>"); /*​*/
        W‌rite(a); /*​*/
        W‌riteLiteral(@"</li>");
    }
}
```

Now with your scenario I assume that your `GetEmail` only return a set of string so change your return type to Customer object to `list<string>` as `public List<string> GetEmails()` and return `ee` as list of string.

Then all you need to do in your razor view like test case scenario.

Comment: returning List<string>; is easier to handle those emails together for me. thanks :)